# Match Text Between The Last / And A?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the ID of a Notion database from a URL e.g. the bold text in `https://www.notion.so/anotioneer/`**`d77d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a`**`?v=1dedd49c5403489ebb899a290111f858`.

I can match everything after `anotioneer/` with `anotioneer\/(.+)` and everything before the `?` with `.*(?=\?)` but I'm struggling to combine the two expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
anotioneer\/(\w+)(?:$|\?)
```

- Start with the last segment of the path: `anotioneer\/`.
- Take one or more alphanumeric characters as a group: `(\w+)`.
- Match either the end of the line or the query string in a non-capturing group: `(?:$|\?)`.

Here's the valid sample data I used:

```
/anotioneer/d77d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a?v=1dedd49c5403489ebb899a290111f858
/anotioneer/d79d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a?v=3dedd49c5403489ebb899a290111f858
/anotioneer/d80d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a?v=4dedd49c5403489ebb899a290111f858&t=123
```

One that doesn't match because there's an extra path segment between `anotioneeer` and the ID:

```
/anotioneer/foo/d78d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a?v=2dedd49c5403489ebb899a290111f858
```

And one that doesn't match because there's an extra path segment after the ID:

```
/anotioneer/d81d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a/foo
```

Here's what the matches look like using this pattern. Note that you'll want to take the first group, not the whole match. That's why we used a non-capturing group for the end-of-line or query string segment.

| Part | Location | Contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 1 | 22-66 | anotioneer/d77d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a? |
| Group 1 | 33-65 | d77d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 2 | 123-167 | anotioneer/d79d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a? |
| Group 1 | 134-166 | d79d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 3 | 224-268 | anotioneer/d80d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a? |
| Group 1 | 235-267 | d80d1d19d4a943358898f2be65499d6a |